# Incrementing input "name" value with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that is using jQuery to generate a "new row" when a button is clicked. When this new row is generated, new inputs are generated. Here is where I got the script from:

chris-barr[dot]com/projects/table_jquery

I am using this code on an order form for a client and I need to specifically target each "name" for the form processing part. The four that are static upon entering the page have "names" like this:

orderType1, orderType2, orderType3, orderType4

So, with each new row that is added, I need to append an incrementing name to each new input that is generated starting at orderType5 and maxing out at orderType10.

**I have max table rows set to 10.

here is my example:

http://www.tdidesign.com/designerorderform.php

I would appreciate any help or insight on how to get started with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are already using an array on **orderType[]**.

Is there a reason you don't want to simply turn this into a multidimensional array?

```
<input name="entry[orderType][]" />
<input name="entry[sampleNeeded][]" />
<input name="entry[yardage][]" />
<input name="entry[pattern][]" />
<input name="entry[manufacturer][]" />
```

Since your POST data will come out in order on the backend you will have everything in perfect ordering for parsing.

Comment: I started to do so because I assumed I would need an array to accomplish this task but I had no luck getting it to work. I think my inexperience with JS is showing through...lol. Whats funny is that I know how to accomplish this with PHP and Actionscript but I can't seem to get it to work in JS! I think its maybe just a formatting issue or something. I appreciate your time. Thanks!

Comment: I am still having difficulty getting this going. I am still having syntax issues and passing the values off to each input as each new row is created. I have some JS books on the way but I still have to get this going. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Jay - Where are the values coming from?  I would suggest you use a library like jQuery so you can easily get the number if inputs using something like `var numEntries = $('input[name^="entry[orderType').length`.  You could then insert values based on the index of the new element, i.e. `$('input[name^="entry[orderType"]').eq(numEntries).val('yourvaluehere')`

Comment: I am using jQuery for adding new rows to a table that has 4 existing rows upon entering the page. So the existing rows have names like "sample1,sample2,sample3, and sample4. I have the max rows set to 6 (total of 10 rows), so when each new row that is created, I need the name "sample" to increment starting at "sample5" to "sample10". So, I was thinking I would just have to have something like: input name="sample[incrementing_number] and just pass a number to "incrementing_number" that would loop starting at 5 and increment til it hits 10.